# Right click menu not showing Lenovo IP 320 15ISK

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

On right click of touchpad not showing the menu and on left click of touchpad file or folder does not gets selected.

I tried setting the primary button as right ... then the menu is shown on right as well as left click..

As the right and left click are in same touchpad and no separate buttons are there. 
Machine congiguration
Machine: Lenovo IP320 15ISK
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

This linked helped https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=107118

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).